# Delete Line if it contains letters - Linux

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, sed

I have this command `sed -i 's/[A-Za-z]//g' file.txt` that gets rid of any letters in my file but now have come to the realization that I need to be a little more steep with these errors.

How can I alter this command to Delete the line completely if there is letters in it?

`000000asd000,12
 000000000000,123`

Would go to this
`000000000000,123`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i '/[a-zA-Z]/d' file.txt
```

The `/.../` command to match lines containing a letter, then `d` to delete the line.

Comment: What would I have to alter on this to print out only the lines it deletes? -@Thomas

Comment: change the `-i` option to `-n`, and change the `d` at the end to `p`

Comment: At that point you might be better off using plain old `grep`.